# JQuery Datatables Table-tools, remove PDF export

Tags: pdf, datatables

I use the table-tools when creating my datatables. This creates the export functionality for Excel, CSV, PDF and Print. I want to remove the PDF options. How is this done?

```
<TABLE aria-describedby="DataTables_Table_1_info" role="grid" id="DataTables_Table_1" class="table table-tools table-dynamic dataTable   " style="">
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution has worked for me put it in fnDrawCallback function

```
$(tableName).dataTable({

 "fnDrawCallback":function () {
                   var table = $(tableName).DataTable();
                   table.buttons('.buttons-pdf').disable();
                      //or

               $(table.buttons('.buttons-pdf').nodes()).css("display", "none");


            } 
});
```